# How to formulate the column S so that I get the desired output as in the scenarios? I need column S to be the higher date among col Q & R

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need column S to be the higher date among col Q & R and if there's no value(-) in one of them, I want the other col value to show in col S, if both have no value(-) , I want "-" to reflect in col S ; like below scenarios, I tried something using IF AND OR, nothing helped
=IF(AND(R2="-",Q2>R2),Q2,"-")

| Q | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-30 | - | 2022-08-30 |
| - | 2022-08-30 | 2022-08-30 |
| 2022-09-10 | 2022-08-30 | 2022-09-10 |
| - | - | - |

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something, please share it with us, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of work from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
=IF(Q2&R2="--","-",MAX(Q2:R2))
```

Option 2:

```
=IF(MAX(Q2:R2)=0,"-",MAX(Q2:R2))
```